# How to alter form password and add current password in user_profile_form

Tags: 7, forms

[image]

How to alter form password and add current password like in this image?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [Password Separate Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/change_pwd_page) module.

The Password Separate Form module provides the separate password change form.

By default it comes with user account page that little bit confusing for end
users. This module would help to make this form as a separate form to help end users, there is no need to change these fields every time if you are editing some other fields on user account page.